# Send HEX through visual basic to TCP/IP Port

Tags: visual-studio, sockets, networking, tcp, hex

Good day to all, continuing with my frustration, y need a way to send hex values through tcp/ip so i can comunicate with my OBD2 interface. for the explanation i used wire shark, Hercules SETUP utility and obviously my code.

i need to send $B0 to the OBD2 box and the box is connected to the LAN and has specific IP & port for it. so it can answer me back with the Firmware Version $92 04 15 and here are the two scenarios.

---

***Hercules Setup utility***

Send B0

Receive 92 04 15

***WireShark***

PC sent 1 byte = b0

box responded 3 byte = 920415

---

***Visual Basic code***

Send B0

Receive     <-- I do not receive nothing

***WireShark***

PC Sent 2 bytes = 4230

box responded 3 byte = 223442     <-- $22 34 xx means do not understand command so box responds "I do not understand your 42 command

---

This is the code i'm using

```
Public Class CLIENT 'client is the forms name

Private Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click 'button1 is the connect button to connect to box
    On Error Resume Next
    Winsock1.Close()
    Winsock1.Connect(TextBox1.Text, 10001) 'I enter the IP of the box here using textbox1 in the form
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_ConnectEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Winsock1.ConnectEvent
    Me.Text = "Connected to server!"
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click ' this is the send button
    On Error Resume Next
    Me.Winsock1.SendData(TextBox2.Text)      'I send what's in textbox2
    Me.RichTextBox1.Text = "me : " & TextBox2.Text & vbCrLf & Me.RichTextBox1.Text      'on textbox1 i display the commands i send
    Me.TextBox2.Text = ""      'I clear textbox2 after sending the message
End Sub
```

I still havent figured out how to receive the data and display it on textbox1, im new on visual basic, i only have a day learning to program, so i ask you to be patient if i don't understand the first time you answer something

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fianlly i could decipher this, remy lebeau you really helped me out, what i did was simply sending like he told me a Byte so a the end this is how it looked like

Me.Winsock1.SendData(&HB0)

and the box responded me back correctly according to the sniffer.. but now im not being able to get the response back displayed

this is the code i implemented.

```
  Private Sub winsock1_DataArrival(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As AxMSWinsockLib.DMSWinsockControlEvents_DataArrivalEvent) Handles winsock1.DataArrival
    Dim dat(e.bytesTotal - 1) As Byte '<<< declare a byte array to store the arriving bytes
    winsock1.GetData(dat, vbByte, dat.Length) ' get the data 
    'add the new message to our chat buffer
    Dim msg As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dat)
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text & vbNewLine & "OBD2 : " & msg & vbCrLf
```

Answer (score 0):

The WinSock control has a [`DataArrival`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228046.aspx) event, which you can use to call the control's [`GetData()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228098.aspx) method.

Comment: ok, i found that part on visual basic thanks. but first i want to know the hex part. write B0 on the text box and that the obdbox reads B0 and not 4230. because it appears that when me.winsoc1.senddata sends it, it converts it to the decimal equivalent of B0. Do you know an answer for that part?

Comment: You are passing a string to `SendData()`. The string value `B0` is actually `$42 $30` in bytes, which is exactly what you are seeing. To send binary data, you need to pass a byte array to `SendData()` instead of a string.